# Can a "Person or Group" column have a repeat user in one entry?

Tags: workflow, column

I am trying to fix a SharePoint 2010 workflow that a co-worker created and I came across this odd case.

The client wants an approver workflow where the same person appears twice in the approval list.  (i.e. he is 2nd and 8th out of 10).  The current workflow saves the list of approvers in a “Person or Group” column, which works fine until this approver does the second approval.  Then it never moves to the next approver.

I suspect that the second time, the workflow adds the user in again and then SharePoint faithfully removed the duplicate entry.  This causes the workflow to think that he has only been notified once and ask him to approve the workflow.

If this is true, is there any way to convince the column to allow the user to appear several times in a cell so that we can see how many times they have been notified?  I suspect the answer is to just use a text line instead, but wanted to see if anyone had any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some further testing, it looks like a "person or group" column will automatically filter out repeats.  Since we actually needed to allow multiple copies of a user or group we ended up storing them in a string and then converting them individually back to a person or group when we need it.